# Creating a sentence from multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery

I am trying to create this Result “Sabre is 12 years old” sentence using the code below in SQL.

```sql
select 
    businessname+' is ' + cast(count(e.id)as varchar(11))
from
    Department d
join 
    EmployeeDepartmentHistory EDH on edh.departmentid = D.departmentid
join 
    employee e on edh.id = e.id
group by 
    name
+' years old'
```

If I were to run this section of the code

```sql
select 
    businessname+' is ' + cast(count(e.id)as varchar(11))
from   
    Department d
join 
    EmployeeDepartmentHistory EDH on edh.departmentid = D.departmentid
join 
    employee e on edh.id = e.id
group by 
    name
```

I will get "Sabre is 12"

But I am having a problem getting the "years old" string at the end.

I am getting this error message with the full code

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Column 'HumanResources.Department.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You need to put the `+' years old'` part at the end of the top line, not at the bottom where it is unintentionally forming a part of the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having some required information like:

1. The structure of the tables, which tables have what columns
2. How the tables are related to each other,
3. What you are trying to fetch (eg. what 'businessname' signifies here)

it becomes little difficult to provide proper suggestion.

So, assuming that:

1. EmployeeDepartmentHistory is the bridge table between Department
   and Employee tables to take care of Many:Many relationship between
   Department and Employee tables
2. One businessname (whichever table it belongs to) has
   many employees (e.id) under it
3. You are trying to calculate the count of employees (e.id) for
   each businessname,

This would be the right query:

```
SELECT businessname+' is ' + CAST(COUNT(e.id) AS VARCHAR(11)) + ' years old' 
FROM   Department d
       JOIN EmployeeDepartmentHistory EDH on edh.departmentid=D.departmentid
       JOIN employee e on edh.id=e.id 
GROUP  BY businessname
```

Comment: @Ricardo please let me know if it helped. Could you please upvote the answer if it helped?